# Proving $(k+1)^n$ is equal to a nested summation with k many sigmas?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How would one go about proving the following identity? $\sum_{i_1=0}^{n}...\sum_{i_k=0}^{n-i_1-...-i_{k-1}}\binom{n}{i_1}...\binom{n-...-i_{k-1}}{i_k}=(k+1)^n$

Some experimentation with Wolfram Alpha leads me to believe it's true, but I have no idea how I would even begin to prove this analytically or combinatorially.

This identity came up in the context of solving the following problem: Let $T$ be a set such that $|T| = n$. How many sequences $S_1 ⊆ S_2 ⊆ ··· ⊆ S_k$ such that $S_i ⊆ T$ for $i = 1, . . . k$ are there?

Comment: The context provided seems to be a sufficient proof of the identity.

Comment: Well, actually, I derived the identity in the context of trying to figure out that problem. The left hand side (the one with the sigmas) is pretty clearly the answer to the question of how many possible sequences there are, but I fail to see how $(k+1)^n$ also answers that question.

Comment: $i_k$ seems to be the number of elements in $S_k\setminus S_{k-1}$.  Once you have chosen the elements in $S_k$ the number of possible ways to choose $S_{k+1}$ is ${n-|S_k|}\choose {i_{k+1}}$ and $|S_k|= i_1 + i_2+\cdots+i_k$.

Comment: $(k+1)^n$ is the number of sequences because each of the $n$ elements can will appear for the first time in either $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_{k-1}, S_k,$ or none of those.  There are $k+1$ possible choices for each of the $n$ elements.

Comment: That's brilliant! I didn't even think of looking at it that way, but it's very obvious in retrospect. Thank you!!

Comment: That's just the multinomial $(1+1+\cdots+1)^n$ in disguise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a fixed value of $k$. We need to find the number of sequences $S_1\subseteq S_2\subseteq\cdots\subseteq S_k$ such that $S_k\subseteq T$ (the first condition allows us to simplify the second). Every one of these sequences can be uniquely identified by a word of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{0,1,\dots,k\}$. This is because WLOG each element in $T$ is given by $t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n$ and each of these elements must be in either no sets, just $S_k$, $S_k$ and $S_{k-1}$, etc. This gives $(k+1)$ different choices for each element which can be assigned a letter in the alphabet previously mentioned and ordered to provide a length $n$ word in which the $l$th letter corresponds to the number of sets that $t_l$ is found within. Finally the number of length $n$ words over this alphabet is just $(k+1)^n$ as there are $(k+1)$ possible letters.